# In Fate, how long should the break between the Worldbuilding Session and the next session be?

Tags: fate, campaign-development, session

I'm going to run my first game in two days, and I'm going to spend the entire day with the two players I'll run it with.

I plan to have a brainstormy worldbuilding session first, to figure out what each players wants to see in the game, what they expect, what kind of character (and world) they want on their hands and such.

After that's done, how long should I take before the first session with them playing as PCs, GMed by me? How long should it be between "Session 0" and "Session 1"? Can it be done in the first day?

P.S.:We are running Fate Accelerated, and right now I don't know for certain what kind of world we'll have. I have many ideas, but I don't want to prepare much before-hand, in case they want something radically different.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your group and your (the GM) resources.

My group has ran both Fate and Dresden Files.  In each we've done the group worldbuilding.

How, it's typically gone in Dresden we've done the world building session first. Then the players in the same session/night if you will, have crafted their characters and the ties between them.

In Fate, many of the players have started coming with the first half of their character already done to the world building session. Then they finish the builds of character and world in the same night.

In both, that typically has left us with little time to get to actual games, and when it has it has been only enough for the opening scene.

The problem is that the GM may not have what it takes to populate and more than start the world after the group world building. If that's the case, then say so to your group! "Hey, thanks, next session we'll get into it but I'll take this and make the beginning stories." Something like that.